# Neural network convergence

Tags: machine-learning

I have deep conv network that recognizes 64*96 1 channel images. 
I have forgot to add normalization to images: (image - image.mean()) / stddev. 
Network converged very fast to 85% or something, but gave a HUGE loss. 
I've found my error, added normalization like this:

```
image = (image - image.mean()) / np.std(image)
```

For some reason it stopped converge at all after that. 
I've tried to increase learning rate but it did not help at all. 
Could anyone please help me to understand what is actually happening?

UPDATE: Changed

```
np.std(image, axis = 0)
```

to

```
np.std(image)
```

Comment: include code, otherwise it is impossible to help

Comment: Here is ipython notebook https://yadi.sk/d/uL-0uZjd3FpRUF Actually I am newbie in machine learning I could make something horrible in that code. Could you please point me to these places and explain what I am dong wrong?

Comment: code should be in the question itself, you should also make it as small and concise as possible. Basically the smallest chunk of code with the problem encountered.

Comment: I understand this, but I am not sure where the problem is. So I have decided to show this 200 lines of code. Also I've hoped that someone will point me on other possible problems in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are facing is due to very high learning rates. High learning rates causes training to give huge loss values at the start and then failing to converge. You should use a lower learning rate from the start and see if the network converges. You can also follow a strategy of reducing learning rate as network is being trained. This [link](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/) will be very helpful for you in training your network.

Comment: Did not help, it always gives me 11% accuracy with and without learning rate decay. Tried Adam and Momentum optimizers - same results.